# Refactoring groovy html markupbuilder

Tags: groovy, groovyshell, markupbuilder

I picked up groovy scripting recently so I'm still a beginner in it 
(I'm also a professional programmer in C with some notions of Java)
I successfully created a valid html page with the MarkupBuilder (see simplified example below)

```
def writer = new StringWriter()
def page_html = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer)
page_html.html
{
    head
    {
        title("Test HTML table")
    }
    body
    {
        h3("Test HTML")
        a 
        {
            mkp.yield("Hello html")
        }
    }
}
writer.toString()
```

All is fine except now the "body" part gets quite large and **I have some code repeating so it really needs refactoring**.
By refactoring, I mean I want to put parts in a function/procedure and call it repeatedly in the "body".

I tried to follow this example 
http://groovy.jmiguel.eu/groovy.codehaus.org/Using+MarkupBuilder+for+Agile+XML+creation.html

Thinking it would work with HTML markup the same as XML. 
EDIT : it does work.

For example if I do something like

```
def my_procedure(builder)
{
   builder.a 
   {
        mkp.yield("Hello html")
   }
}
```

and

```
def writer = new StringWriter()
def page_html = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer)
page_html.html
{
    head
    {
        title("Test HTML table")
    }
    body
    {
        h3("Test HTML")
        my_procedure(page_html)
    }
}
writer.toString()
```

EDIT: you get a failure at execution if don't write builder.a but only "a" in the procedure

Thanks,
Clement

Comment: With groovy 2.4.5 it returns correct result.

Comment: You might also be interested in the [MarkupTemplateEngine](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/markup-template-engine.html). It would allow you to define a base template class that contains your utility methods, while being significantly faster.

Comment: @Opal my bad, I got it right in the post but wrong in my code (a builder.td was missing) so I edited the post to reflect that.

To melix thanks for the suggestion. I saw some bits about using a template around the web but it seems a bit too advanced for me right now

Comment: @CMFR How would you like it to work? You need to invoke `a` in some context. So `builder.a` will be ok, or `builder.with { a// some code}`.

Comment: @Opal sure in this example forgetting the 'builder' is obvious. In my real-world case the first reference to a html element was deep inside if..else constructions.
thanks for builder.with I'll look into it as I never used it.

Comment: @CMFR, so please provide an example that shows the real problem.